# Remove and replace Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can remove the element in JS and to move inside another class. I have tried multiple ways but its throwing an error.

```
<div class="posts container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="posts-item col-md-7 col-xs-12 p-0">
                 Abc
            </div>
             <ul>                
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog">
    XYZ
    </div>
```

I am trying to get output like using Javascript

```
   <div class="posts container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="posts-item col-md-7 col-xs-12 p-0">
                 Abc
            </div>
             <div class="blog">
             XYZ
            </div>
             <ul>                
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Iam trying to move the class name "blog" inside "posts-item".

Comment: _"I have tried multiple ways"_ please demonstrate this, along with the errors. We prefer a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Can you explain more ? Also, haven't you tried anything.

Comment: What did you try? What is the error?

Comment: In your sample output, `.blog` isn't inside `.posts-item`. However, a simple `parent.appendChild(child)` should do it...

Comment: ``` var elem = document.querySelector(".blog");
var elem1 = document.querySelector(".blog");
elem1.remove()
    document.querySelector(".posts-item")[0].appendChild("elem");
​
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:59

```

Comment: Ramya, in your code I think the array index on the end of ```document.querySelector(".posts-item")[0]``` might be an error. document.querySelector returns a single element, unlike querySelectorAll. Also quotes around elem are I think an error. Try ```document.querySelector(".posts-item").appendChild(elem)``` or ```document.querySelectorAll(".posts-item")[0].appendChild(elem)``` (

Comment: ...also ```var elem1 = document.querySelector(".blog"); elem1.remove() ``` can probably be removed: appending an element somewhere else removes it from where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use insertBefore for moved your item:

```
const referenceNode = document.querySelector('.posts-item')
referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(document.querySelector('.blog'), referenceNode.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, which works in Chrome for me, for the result you describe in the text:

```js
document.querySelector('.posts-item').append(document.querySelector('.blog'))
```

...or to get the result you've illustrated, perhaps this:

```js
document.querySelector('.posts-item').after(document.querySelector('.blog'))
```

You may need to modify the selectors if there are more elements sharing the classes used.

See docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append